# Y-Axis with custom ticks and 0 always in the middle

Tags: chart.js

I tried to create an y-axis with the these ticks: [-49.8, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 999].  I always have three ticks above 0 and three ticks below 0. The interval between the ticks are not linear.

I want to achieve that the 0 tick is always in the middel of the axis. Like this:
[image: achieve]

My axis setup is this:

```
y: {
    position: 'right',
    max: 999,
    min: -49.8,
    afterTickToLabelConversion: function (chart) {
        chart.ticks = [];
        chart.ticks.push({ value: -49.8, label: "-49.8" });
        chart.ticks.push({ value: -20, label: "-20" });
        chart.ticks.push({ value: -10, label: "-10" });
        chart.ticks.push({ value: 0, label: "0" });
        chart.ticks.push({ value: 10, label: "10" });
        chart.ticks.push({ value: 20, label: "20" });
        chart.ticks.push({ value: 999, label: "999" });
    },
},
```

but the result is the following:
[image]

Comment: Probably, what you want is not just place the ticks, but change the scaling of the axis, which will also impact where data will be placed. The available axis is linear so the ticks are placed correctly. There's also the logarithmic axis, which can only be used with positive values, and if negative data is not connected to positive data, you can combine it with a linear negative by [stacking](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scales/stacked.html). Otherwise, you can (create your own type of axis)(https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/axes.html) with any kind of scaling.